# textbf doesn't work with txfonts package

Tags: fonts

If I compile this, it won't work - the text won't be bold.

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Something}
\end{document}
```

If I remove the package usage, it'll work, but I do need it. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  The `IL2` font encoding is unfamiliar to me.  Does removing that help?  Also note that there are newer packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` that might be better choices.

Answer (score 3):

The log file tells you

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `IL2/txr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `IL2/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `IL2/txr/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `IL2/txr/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

meaning that `txfonts` doesn't support the IL2 encoding (just a few fonts do) and the standard Computer Modern font is used instead.